# Making Tables Out of Hierarchical Lists in CSS

Tags: css, styling

This should be easy, or perhaps impossible :)

I have this kind of HTML output

```
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two
      <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

and I would like it to appear as

```
one two three
    a   b
```

how can I do this with pure CSS? I can modify the HTML to some extent if necessary (but I would rather not).

Comment: Are you sure you want the b to appear under the three? What if the three list item has a child list too - where does that go?

Comment: wheresrhys, actually, no, I want the a to be flush left, but I only realized it after asking. The problem seems to be this: I don't think I can stop the HTML from being hierarchical (in other words, the a and b are always children of the two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with some floats and absolute positioning

```
ul li { list-style-type: none; display: inline; float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
ul.first {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
ul li ul li ul{ list-style-type: none; display: inline; float: left;position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 0; margin-top: 30px;}
ul.second {position: absolute; top: 30; left: 50;}
```

and

```
<ul class="first">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two
      <ul class="second">
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: really? I'll have to try this out immediately. If it works you'll win best answer and my undying gratitude until the project gets changed and this answer doesn't even get used :)

Answer (score 4):

You're asking about "pure" CSS.  Pure CSS is to use the best semantic tag for the job, and that means that if you really have tabular data, which this looks like it might be, than you *should* use a table.

Comment: was just thinking that same thing and I was going to add it to the question. Problem is then I have to get in there and futz with the templates that produce the HTML, but yes, I guess that's why I get paid. Thanks.

Comment: +1.  Tables get a bad wrap for being overused in page layouts for so many years (when there weren't good alternatives).  However, there's nothing wrong with using HTML tables for tabular data.  In fact it's typically the cleanest, easiest, and most cross-browser-friendly way to do it.

Comment: What if you don't have control of the HTML? Then you'd use Zac's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css tag "list-style-type:none" ie

ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

ul li ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

Comment: That's the _first_ step, but it's incomplete because it won't line things up like he wants.

Comment: oops forgot you have to add a "display: inline;" as well.

Comment: okay, that's cool, but the problem -- and it's probably not solvable in CSS -- is to get the second line as the second line and not interrupting the first.

Comment: With your current HTML, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to pull it off without using CSS2 child selectors and positioning each element.

Answer (score 0):

To take Zac's answer a little further, you can do the CSS addressing without modifying the HTML whatsoever. Then it would look like this:

```
<style>
ul li { list-style-type: none; display: inline; float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
ul  {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
ul li ul li ul{ list-style-type: none; display: inline; float: left;position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0; margin-top: 30px;}
ul li ul {position: absolute; top: 20; left: 0;}
</style>

<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two
      <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```